# Volume between $xy=1,xy=9,xz=4,xz=36,xy=25,yz=49$

Tags: integration, linear-transformations, volume, jacobian

So I have this surfaces $xy=1,xy=9,xz=4,xz=36,yz=25,yz=49$ But I could not identify the region so I tried transforming it.$$u=xy\quad\quad v=xz \quad\quad w=yz$$ which turns them into planes.

But now I am confused on how to use the partial derivatives jacobian.

The determinant of the matrix $\frac{\delta(x,y,z)}{\delta(u,v,w)} $ led me to $-2xyz$ but now how can I find the integral  in this $uvw$ coordinates? $$\int_{25}^{49}\int_4^{36}\int_1^9 dudvdw$$ But I know I have to use in that integral somenthing related to the Jacobian, not sure what

Comment: Look up the (multidimensional) change of variables formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $uvw=x^2y^2z^2$. If your $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive, just take the square root

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake passing from the notebook to the pc

Comment: Ohhhhh yesss now I see it. So the partial derivatives matrix becomes $\frac{1}{2uvw}$ and now I have the integral.
$$\int_{25}^{49}\int_4^{36}\int_1^9 \frac{1}{2\sqrt{uvw}} dudvdw$$ wich gives me 64 thank you